# Load Wordpress posts in chunks 100 at a time with Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I would like some help to change a bit og Jquery/Ajax code. The following code loads a new Wordpress post every time i scroll to the bottom

```
jQuery(function($){
    var page = 1;
    var loading = true;
    var $window = $(window);
    var $content = $("body #ordrene");
    var load_posts = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type       : "GET",
                data       : {numPosts : 1, pageNumber: page},
                dataType   : "html",
                url        : "http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/loopHandler.php",
                beforeSend : function(){
                    if(page != 1){
                        $content.append('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center">' +
                            '<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />' +
                            '</div>');
                    }
                },
                success    : function(data){
                    $data = $(data);
                    if($data.length){
                        $data.hide();
                        $content.append($data);
                        $data.fadeIn(500, function(){
                            $("#temp_load").remove();
                            loading = false;
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#temp_load").remove();
                    }
                },
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#temp_load").remove();
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }
        });
    }
    $window.scroll(function() {
        var content_offset = $content.offset();
        console.log(content_offset.top);
        if(!loading && ($window.scrollTop() +
            $window.height()) > ($content.scrollTop() + $content.height() + content_offset.top)) {
                loading = true;
                page++;
                load_posts();
        }
    });
    load_posts();
});
```

On my site i have about 1000 posts, all which i want to display on one page so that i am able to sort them with Jquery Sortable. But the server i am on can't handle that many posts loading i one go, so i would like to ue ajax to break the query to the database up into multiple chunks.

Therefor i would like to alter the code above (or get advice on brand new code) to do the following: On page load, get 100 posts. When the first 100 posts are loaded, fetch 100 more, And so on until all my Wordpress posts are loaded.

If anyone is able to help me, i would really appreciate it!

Anders

**UPDATE:**

My loopHandler.php file looks like this

```
<?php
// Our include
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

// Our variables
$numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;
$page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

echo $numPosts;
echo $page;

$kundenavn = get_the_title();
$category_id = get_cat_ID($kundenavn);

query_posts('cat=' . $category_id . '&posts_per_page=' . $numPosts . '&paged=' . $page);    

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    //Content of the loop 

<?php       
endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var page = 1;
  var loading = true;
  var $window = $(window);
  var $content = $("body #ordrene");
  var load_posts = function() {
    console.log("Loading posts, page is:",page);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: {numPosts: 100, pageNumber: page}, //changed this
      dataType: "html",
      url: "http://www.kundelogg.no/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/loopHandler.php",
      beforeSend: function() {
        if (page !== 1) {
          $content.append('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center">' +
                  '<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />' +
                  '</div>');
        }
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Received data, length is:",data.length);
        $data = $(data);
        if ($data.length) {
          $data.hide();
          $content.append($data);
          $data.fadeIn(500, function() {
            $("#temp_load").remove();
            loading = false;
          });
        } else {
          $("#temp_load").remove();
        }
        if (data === "")//make sure php returns empty string if no more posts
          return;
        pageNumber++;//added this
        load_posts();//added this
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#temp_load").remove();
        alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
  };
  load_posts();
});
```

Comment: It seems that this is almost working like i want it to. But it appears that it only gets posts one time. the only thin missing is to get it to start over again if there are more posts available and keep running until all posts are fetched

Comment: @user2674339 do you get any errors? the code I posted should work but when there are no more posts your site doesn't return an empty string so it'll run forever (see the comment). After pageNum++ I call load_posts again so it should keep fetching unless there is an error or you are appending the posts to the wrong element.

Comment: No, i don't get any errors. I have one file with the "original" query named orders.php that runs on page load fetching 10 posts (posts_per_page=10). Then Ajax kicks in and uses the loopHandler.php which you can se above in the update to my post. Now Ajax is supposed to load 100 more posts, and then 100 more. But it stops after the first 100, giving me a total of 110 posts. 10 form the original page load and 100 from Ajax fetching more posts once. No errors, the one time it runs, it runs smoothly. Im appending the posts to the first surrounding div element. I Have played around with no result.

Comment: @user2674339 Updated the answer with some console logs. You can see the console output when you press F12 in Chrome. It should log that it's fetching data multiple times. Also the network tab may show some useful information about the xhr requests made.

Comment: The same problem still occurs, it only runs one time, but now it is visible in the console which is very good. Don't know how to fix it though. Something is wrong with the pageNumber. Se Screenshot of console: http://ge.tt/14Npf091/v/0?c

Comment: @user2674339 If you give me the url of the page that contains the code I can have a look.

Comment: Sadly i am unable to provide you with the URL of the site. I understand it would be very practical in order to solve the problem, but my hands are tied on that matter.